# Extend the default behaviour of AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

I want to customise the way AutoMapper converts my types without losing the features already implemented by AutoMapper.

I could create a custom `ITypeConverter` instance but I can't see how to invoke the default behaviour.

```csharp
Mapper.CreateMap<MyDomainObject, MyDto>
      .ConvertUsing<MyTypeConverter>();
```

...

```csharp
public class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter<MyDomainObject, MyDto>
{
    public MyDto ConvertCore(MyDomainObject source)
    {
        var result = // Do the default mapping.

        // do my custom logic

        return result
    }
}
```

If I try to call `var result = Mapper.Map<MyDto>(source)` it gets into an infinite loop. I effectively want AutoMapper to do everything it normally would assuming there was no TypeConverter defined.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to customise some values on the destination object, then you're better off with a [Custom Value Resolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) - TypeConverters are designed to handle the whole conversion.

The doc page listed above will have enough to get you started: when you have implemented the CustomResolver you apply it like this, and AutoMapper will do the default mapping for the other properties:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyDomainObject, MyDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TargetProperty, 
               opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
```